# Convert Sting to [x, y] coordinates in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, maps, coordinates

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var src = [40.6976, -74.2598];

  function convertToDMS(src) {
    function toDMS(n) {
      n = Math.abs(n);
      var d = Math.floor(n);
      n = n - d;
      n *= 60;
      var m = Math.floor(n);
      n = n - m;
      n *= 60;
      var s = Math.floor(n);
      return "" + d + " " + m + " " + s;
    }

    var dir0 = src[0] > 0 ? "N" : "S";
    var dir1 = src[1] > 0 ? "E" : "W";

    console.log(toDMS(src[0]) + dir0);
    console.log(toDMS(src[1]) + dir1);
  }

  convertToDMS(src);
</script>
<div id="locationdiv">[40.6976,-74.2598]</div>
```

Using the script above I am able to get degree, minute and second like 40°41'46.0"N+74°18'08.0"W

```
However if instead of using 
var src = [40.6976,-74.2598];
I use
var src = document.getElementById("locationdiv").innerHTML;
```

the script does not work with no error in console. How do I convert the innerHTML which comes as a string to the form [40.6976,-74.2598] which can be used.

Comment: You can simply parse it as JSON, but you should be using `textContent` or `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`. `const src = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("locationdiv").innerText);`

Comment: Can you give me a short description on how to parse it as JSON if possible using the coordinates I have give. Thank You

Comment: [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: @pilchard when unsure what to use, stick to `textContent`. A habit of using `innerText` (just *cause* of its similarity to *innerHTML*) will bite you sooner or later.

Comment: `toDMS` should be better placed outside of the parent function scope. Reusability, remember? Also `return \`${d} ${m} ${s}\`;` looks way better.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I agree and default to `textContent` myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `typeof` is `"string"`
If true — convert the argument value to Object using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
function toDMS(n) {
  n = Math.abs(n);
  const d = Math.floor(n);
  n = n - d;
  n *= 60;
  const m = Math.floor(n);
  n = n - m;
  n *= 60;
  const s = Math.floor(n);
  return `${d}° ${m}' ${s}"`;
}

function convertToDMS(latLng) {

  if (typeof latLng === "string") latLng = JSON.parse(latLng);
  const [lat, lng] = latLng;

  const dirLat = lat > 0 ? "N" : "S";
  const dirLng = lng > 0 ? "E" : "W";

  console.log(`${toDMS(lat)} ${dirLat}`);
  console.log(`${toDMS(lng)} ${dirLng}`);
}

convertToDMS([40.6976, -74.2598]);
convertToDMS(document.querySelector("#locationdiv").textContent);
```

```html
<div id="locationdiv">[40.6976,-74.2598]</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ Roko C. Buljan, it worked like a charm.

Comment: @chiefdakwa you're very welcome